# Is it possible to insert one model in another?

Tags: django, django-models

I have few models. Let's say in home.html I'm using Page model to create simple page structure via admin panel. Now I want add and display inside page multiple galleries. How I should do that ? Is it possible to have inside Page model (in my admin panel) fields with Gallery model ?

```py
class Page(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(efault=True)
    display_order = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    meta_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    meta_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name  = 'Home page'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
class Gallery(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = OptimizedImageField(upload_to='gallery')
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Gallery'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} {self.title}'
```

[admin panel visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ungwR.jpg)

Comment: how about OneToMany relationship from Page model to Gallery model? So that on your template, you could do something like this: `{% for gallery in page.gallery_set.all %} {{ gallery }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: But right know in Gallery model I have single images. If I need many galleries do I have to create many gallerie models? Because when I'm in admin panel I see all galleries models in a rows and inside them single images. Is it possible to have one main GALLERY "folder" and inside all galleries ? I want to be able to create themes like: some content, gallery1, some content, galler2 and so one..

Comment: `one main GALLERY "folder" and inside all galleries`, I'm not understand your context. Could you provide what you've done with your idea or somehow you could provide a UI mockup or something into your question? that would be easier for other people to understand what you want and how to help.

Comment: I edited my question and added image in the bottom. I have no clue how to achieve this so mayby it's even not possible or there is a better solution than I think of.

Comment: I think you might want to use ManyToMany, so that on each subpage, you can select multiple gallery on that subpage. Let's say you want S1 has gallery G1, G2, G3, subpage S2 has gallery G2, G3, subpage S3 has gallery G1, G3. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. But my question is still about Gallery model. Do I need to create multiple Galleries models to achieve that? Or (like on image I attached to question ) I can somehow put this all together and be DRY?

Comment: If Yes then No, you don't have to create multiple Galleries models. Just need to create a field on Page model `galleries` with ManyToMany relationship, e.g: `galleries = models. ManyToManyField('Gallery')`, you could take a look at the example from Django to map with your situation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: I don't think you understand me correctly :). With your solution I will still have one Gallery model with all images inside. I thougth that I'd have a choice between whole galleries instead of select single images in my subpage admin panel. Is it possible?

Comment: I would like to start a chat with you in here but need 20 reputation. Anyway, I don't really understand your sentences, this sentense `still have one Gallery model with all images inside`, I don't understand what `all images inside` mean. If that was me, I will create another model to store images, has OneToMany field on Gallery to link to Images. Then still allow pages have more than one Gallery so it will be ManyToMany between Pages and Gallery. sorry, I'm so lost..

Comment: I try one more time to explain. We have 2 models - Gallery and Subpage.
When I'm enter django admin panel I have those 2 models. Then I enter Gallery model, inside I can add objects which are single images - right? So even if I make OneToMany or ManyToMany field in Subpage all of these images will be listed in this one Gallery model - right?

Comment: So let's say I will add 100 images, they are all inside this one Gallery model so I don't know which image is related with which subpage. And my question is - can I somehow separte single images to groups in this Gallery model? So when I'm creating subpage, in gallery field I can choose i.e. gallery1 (which contain few images), gallery2( other few images), instead of picking single images from gallery field list.

Comment: Yeah, you can create another model for example: `Image`, and then inside gallery you could create a field `images=OneToManyField('Image')`, then on the admin page, when you create new gallery, you just need to add new image and then link to the gallery. On page model, add this field `galleries=ManyToManyField('Gallery')` so whenever you create a new Page, you could choose which gallery you want to link to that page. After all, when you create a page, you can choose multiple gallery for 1 page, and with these galleries, you can get images inside each gallery.

Comment: It works. Thank you! Could you just tell me one more thing. How now call to this objects in template ?

Comment: Which objects @dawhry? `images`?

Comment: If you have page on the context then you could do something like this to get the images. {% for gallery in page.galleries.all %} {% for image in gallery.images.all %} <img src="{{image}}" /> {% endfor %} {% endfor %}

Comment: Chosen gallery with images, Let say I want loop over and display all.